# Outlook filter that filters non-"mydomain" emails / calendar events

Tags: filter, outlook, rules

I have tried a few different options to try and create a filter for emails (only emails - not calendar, voicemails, tasks etc) that are not from "my-company.com" but not very successful.

what I need is a filter/rule that captures all emails (only emails) from external folks (not from my-company.com domain)

thanks

Comment: Do not cross-post questions: https://superuser.com/questions/1245516/outlook-filter-that-filters-non-mydomain-emails-calendar-events

Answer (score 0):

Check for `MailItem.SenderAddressType == "SMTP"`. Address type of the senders from inside your own Exchange org will be "EX".

Comment: I tried - message header match "what you suggested" - but did not work.

Comment: I don't think I have ever mentioned message headers. Is this a programming question?

Comment: sorry - then I didn't understand. How/where do I include this filter in outlook ?

Comment: I am looking for an outlook filter.

Comment: StackOverflow is for the programming questions. End user questions are better answered at https://superuser.com/